# DataTables "Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to make a function to create a new DataTable. If a table already exists, I would like my function destroy the existing table and create the new one.

I did this:

```
$.ajax().done(function(response){
            Init_DT(response['cols'], response['data']);
        });

function Init_DT(cols, data){

        if($('#mytable tr').length > 0){
            table.destroy();
        }

        var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
            "data": data,
            "columns": cols
        });

    }
```

This function works well to initiate my first table but I get "Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined" on subsequent calls.

Comment: On first call the length of the table = 0 so table.destroy isn't called. Then it create the datatable instance. But on the second call, when length >0, it can't destroy it.

Comment: You are right. But is it not a local scope variable ? and when second time you come in. it is REALLY NOT DEFINED. because table was destroyed when outside the function ? it will only be created after you check destroy ? for reference --> http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: True. But even if I do `table = $('#mytable').dataTable();`, which should be global, I got the same error. Any suggestion @Meer?

Comment: Can you show the code what you just tried ?

Comment: What is the SOME ERROR ?

Comment: @Meer Made some edits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62890/discussion-between-wistar-and-meer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local JavaScript Variables.

a variable defined inside a function has a Local Scope. It is destroyed when function finishes.

```
function myFunction() {
var myVar = "value";}
```

this function myVar will be destroyed after the function has done its work. in the next call it will be defined again.

Use global variable. i.e define it outside the function and then use it.
i.e

```
var myVar='value';function myFunction(){//here myVar can be accessed}
```

or inside your function assign a value to a variable it will become global.

```
function myFunction(){ myVar = 'value'; }
```

now myVar will also be global.

Therefore you need to use

```
table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
            "data": data,
            "columns": cols
        });
```

reference: [w3Schools JS Variable Scope](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)