# Cannot read property 'oFeatures' of undefined datatables

Tags: datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I am getting this error Cannot read property 'oFeatures' of undefined datatables I am using bubble editing of datatable editor

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var editor;
$(document).ready(function(){
 // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples
 

    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    ajax: 'http://52.77.155.163/web/index.php?r=ivision/productprices/datatable',

        table: '#example',
        
        fields: [ {
                label: "Id:",
                name: "id"
            }, 
            
        ],
        formOptions: {
            inline: {
                onBlur: 'submit'
            }
        }
    } );

    
$('#example').on( 'click', 'tbody td', function (e) {
        var index = $(this).index();
 
        if ( index === 0 ) {
            editor.bubble( this );
        }
});

var table=$('#example').DataTable( {
        ajax: 'http://52.77.155.163/web/index.php?r=ivision/productprices/datatable',
        dom: "Bfrtip",
        scrollY: 300,
        paging: false,
        bSort: false,
        columns: [
            { data: "id" },
            { data: "getcat(cat_id)" },
            { data: "getproduct(p_id)" },
            { data: "m_price" },
            { data: "c_price" },
            { data: "e_price" },
            
            {
                data: null,
                defaultContent: '<a href="#" class="remove">Delete</a>',
                orderable: false
            }],
            buttons: [
            { extend: "create", editor: editor },
            { extend: "edit",   editor: editor },
            { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
        
        ],

    } );




}); 



</script>
```

I am getting this error in console, Cannot read property 'oFeatures' of undefined . I am using bubble editing for datatables.net editor.

Comment: providing a code example would help a great deal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataTables "Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26316294/datatables-cannot-read-property-destroy-of-undefined)

Comment: HI, I have added the code, now can you give me some help @Chris Hopkins

Answer (score 4):

I also get this error.

It was the issue, Editor's table property is different DataTable Id.

After use same Id, it's fixed.

Comment: Worked like a charm  Also remember when creating the datatable to use the API instance => `$('#table').DataTable({` and not use a Object like this => `$('#table').dataTable({`